# How can I use ImGui to render simple text instead of using stb_truetype directly?

Tags: opengl, textures, fonts, text

Since [ImGui](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui) builds on top of [stb_truetype](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_truetype.h) for its font rendering, I thought it could be nicer to use its already built font-processing capabilities (`ImGui::GetIO().Fonts`), and render with those, instead of using `stb_truetype` directly.

However, I've been having trouble figuring out how to do this, specifically how to get quad position/texture coordinates for a given string to use with the preloaded texture at `ImGui::GetIO().Fonts->TexID`.

I'm not looking to draw buttons/text inside ImGui windows, all I want to do is to use ImGui to build vertex data for a given string so that I can render it anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

From the [GitHub issue you opened](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/issues/628) and the [ImgUi FAQ](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/blob/v1.60/imgui.cpp#L623):

Create a dummy window with `NoTitleBar|NoResize|NoMove|NoScrollbar|NoSavedSettings|NoInputs`, then you can retrieve the `ImDrawList*` via `GetWindowDrawList()` and draw to it in any way you like.

Comment: the "Imgui FAQ" link is broken

Comment: @Anentropic fixed. thanks!